# How to delete Entity is generated from generate:doctrine:entity

Tags: php, symfony

I create an Entity by using commandline `php app/console generate:doctrine:entity`.
Now I want to delete that Entity(yml, schema..). I delete Doctrine yml file and Entity directory but when I use command line `doctrine:schemal:create` that always create Table which name = that Entity in Database?

Answer (score 5):

To delete a generated entity, please delete the yml that contains the schema, which is located in BundleName/Resources/config/doctrine/entityName.orm.yml file. Then, delete the entityName.php in BundleName/Entities/  and clear the cache using

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

Comment: Thanks @Praveesh,
I delete all entity and cache:clear but when I use doctrine:schemal:create command, that table is created in database :(

Answer (score 4):

after removing the entity and clearing the cache try this command : **doctrine:schema:update --force --complete**

Comment: Can't do that :(. This is screenshort. I deleted all entity Home but i dont know why it's still "Create Table Home()..." :(
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-CpE32QYVcUo/U2e8KcOB2QI/AAAAAAAADfE/8ICPeHm_8t0/w800-h600-no/delete+entity.jpg